How to enable "find in page" in a Tauri app?
I am making a tauri app which displays large HTML documents (university coursework).
It would be really useful if I could enable the default browser "Find in page" functionality, but I haven't found how to do it.
I did see an issue on their repo to remove this behaviour, so perhaps it is working on some systems and not others?
At least for me on MacOS 14.5 and the latest version of Tauri, cmd+f and fn+f3 both don't seem to open a searchbox.
Thanks.
